# Parse multiple URLs and extract data

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup, parse-url

1. I need to parse a HTML page, get all the URLs meeting my requirement.
2. Now, I need to parse each of the extracted URLs to get the data that I want, if the page title matches something and save them to multiple files based on their names. 
   I have done part 1 in the following way.

   ```
   pattern=re.compile(r'''class="topline"><A href="(.*?)"''')
   da = pattern.search(web_page)
   da = pattern.findall(soup1)
   col_width = max(len(word) for row in da for word in row)
   for row in da:
       if "some string" in row.upper():
           bb = "".join(row.ljust(col_width))
           print >> links, bb
   ```

I'd truly appreciate any help.
Thank you.

Comment: Use BeutifulSoup or any other library for parsing HTML, do not use regex. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/969365

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, [do not parse HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). You've actually marked the question with `BeautifulSoup` tag, but you are still using regular expressions here.

Here's how you can get the links, follow them and check the `title`:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "url here"

soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(URL))
links = soup.select('.topline > a')
for a in links:
    link = link.get('href')
    if link:
        # follow link
        link_soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(link))
        title = link_soup.find('title')
        # check title
```

`.topline > a` [CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) would find you any tag with `topline` class and get the `a` tag right beneath.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. It definitely helped.